# Windows 7 external NTP

Tags: windows-7, ntp

I have a Windows 7 pc that is part of a domain but for research needs it has to be syncronized with a GPS server (not part of the domain). 
I know that time discrepancy between the domain controller time and the pc could cause some issues but I have to do it nevertheless.

I tried following several guides (I'm linking some reference):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/it-IT/88820676-3bce-4464-a7ba-0b38ebcc9267/synchronize-system-clock-with-extern-ntp-server-for-windows-7?forum=w7itpronetworking

http://www.timetoolsglobal.com/2013/06/21/how-to-synchronize-microsoft-windows-to-a-ntp-server-1/

After changing my registry entry with my reachable NTP ip address (I can ping it), restarting and resyncronizing windows time I still get my domain controller time. If I check the registry it has the enable external ntp server but it seems to be ignored.

How can I force it ?

Comment: Do you have access to the domain GPOs?

Comment: Check the following commands: `w32tm /query /status`, `w32tm /query /peers`in an elevated prompt. Do they show your DC or something else?

Comment: They both show me my DC.

Comment: And I haven't access to domain GPOs, I opened the local ones instead of the domain ones

Comment: Run `gpresult /h <path\report.html>` and look up if any GPO is set for NTP client.

Comment: Why is it that you're not using a non-domain joined computer for this research?

Comment: Yes, is applied the domain GPO Configure NTP Client setting.

Comment: @joeqwerty I can't. Workplace policy ...

Answer (score 0):

I had to contact the IT because the GPO domain was enforcing the NTP server. 
They allowed the changes in some of our pcs and now everything is working fine.